# Get class hierarchy dot file from doxygen

Tags: doxygen, graphviz, dot

Doxygen generates a nice class hierarchy for my project using graphviz. But I now want to add manual annotations to that graph. For that I need to edit the DOT file. However doxygen doesn't seem to output that file anywhere. It only outputs a `.map` file and the `.png` image.

How do I get doxygen to give me the dot file? I checked their documentation, but couldn't find any way to achieve it. Surely doxygen has to produce the dot file at some stage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you set `DOT_CLEANUP` to `NO` in doxygen's configuration file, doxygen will not remove the .dot files.